# Animating children before Parent in Framer motion

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I am trying to make a dropdown menu, so when I click on the hamburger menu, the animation happens the parent div animate from `height: 0` to `height: auto`, while the `Links` only go from `opacity 0 to 1` feels like they are position `absolute` but they are `relative`, I tried `transition: { when: "afterChildren" }` but it didn't affect anything, so how I make the parent animate when the animation of the children's are done?

I want this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-2-animating-shared-layouts-1cpd0) kind of animation when clicking on the menu

**My Code :**

```
 <AnimateSharedLayout>
        <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
          {isMobileMenuOpen && (
            <motion.div
              layout
              initial={{ opacity: 0, height: 0 }}
              animate={{ opacity: 1, height: "auto" }}
              exit={{
                opacity: 0,
                height: 0,
                transition: { when: "afterChildren" },
              }}
              transition={{ duration: 0.5, staggerChildren: 0.3 }}
              className={styles.mobileMenu}
            >
              <Link
                onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(!isMobileMenuOpen)}
                className={
                  location.pathname === "/works" ? styles.activeLink : ""
                }
                to='/works'
                data-content='Works'
              >
                <AnimatePresence>
                  <motion.span
                    layout
                    initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
                    animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                    exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
                  >
                    Works
                  </motion.span>
                </AnimatePresence>
              </Link>
              <Link
                onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(!isMobileMenuOpen)}
                to='/blog'
                className={
                  location.pathname === "/blog" ? styles.activeLink : ""
                }
                data-content='Blog'
              >
                <AnimatePresence>
                  <motion.span
                    layout
                    initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
                    animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                    exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
                  >
                    Blog
                  </motion.span>
                </AnimatePresence>
              </Link>
              <Link
                onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(!isMobileMenuOpen)}
                to='/contact'
                className={
                  location.pathname === "/contact" ? styles.activeLink : ""
                }
                data-content='Contact'
              >
                <AnimatePresence>
                  <motion.span
                    layout
                    initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
                    animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                    exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
                  >
                    Contact
                  </motion.span>
                </AnimatePresence>
              </Link>
            </motion.div>
          )}
        </AnimatePresence>
      </AnimateSharedLayout>
```